# To what values are GLSL variables initialized by default?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I know that in c and c++, the variables are uninitialized by default. On the other hand in java they are initialized to 0 or null by default.

What is the corresponding default initialization in GLSL?
Specifically, what are the default values when we create the following variables?

`int val;`

`vec4 arr[20];`

Comment: What about the int and array of int, I found two devices one initializes to 0 and other to random value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the [storage qualifier of the variable in question.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Storage_qualifiers) `uniform` variables are always initialized to 0/false. `const`-qualified variables cannot be uninitialized. All other uninitialized variables either get their contents from external resources (UBOs and the like) or have undefined values.

Comment: Why are things in GLSL not documented in a straight forward way as in C or Java?

Comment: @YadavDhakal: Personally, I think relying on the behavior of what happens when you don't provide an initializer is a code smell. If its value matters, it's *always* best to be explicit. Also, I discovered (most of) this by just searching for "initial" in the GLSL specification.